# Filter array depending on two other arrays efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have data which could be simply explained with these three arrays (although in a much larger scale):

```
var arrayOfVariables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'];
var arrayWithValues = [20, 10, 30, 40];
var arrayToFilter = ['var1', 'var3'];
```

Ideally I would want to filter the arrayToFilter and see if it contains any variable from my arrayOfVariables. If they do I want to use their indexes to get an array of correct values from the arrayWithValues. This means var1 = 20, var2 = 10, var3 = 30, var4 = 40. Because arrayToFilter contain var1 och var 3 my last array would be:

```
var output = [20, 30];
```

Does anyone know if this is possible in a efficient way, preferably without for-loops or similar. Maybe filter/map/reduce?

*** UPDATE ***

```
var arrayOfVariables = ['var3', 'var2', 'var1', 'var4'];
var arrayWithValues = [30, 10, 20, 40];
var arrayToFilter = ['var1', 'var3'];
```

If I would change the order of the arrays to the above I would still like an output of [20, 30]. This means I want the values sorted after the arrayToFilter: So first var1 (20) and then var3 (30).

Comment: A better format would be if you constructed a `Map` with the key/value pairs taken from the first two arrays.

Comment: @4castle, that works only if all values are in the variables array. if not, the it produces `undefined` for missing items.

Comment: @NinaScholz The missing items can be checked using `has`. The point of using `Map` is that it has much faster lookup times than a call to `indexOf` or `includes`. It makes the quadratic solution into a linear one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter the values by taking the index and look if the value is in the filter array.

```js
var variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'],
    values = [20, 10, 30, 40],
    filter = ['var1', 'var3', 'foo'],
    result = values.filter((_, i) => filter.includes(variables[i]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Version with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It works only for existing values in `variables`.

```js
var variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'],
    values = [20, 10, 30, 40],
    filter = ['var1', 'var3', 'foo'],
    result = filter.map(f => values[variables.indexOf(f)]);
    
console.log(result);
```

A *4castle*'s approach with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'],
    values = [20, 10, 30, 40],
    filter = ['var1', 'var3'],
    map = new Map(variables.map((v, i) => [v, values[i]]))
    result = filter.map(f => map.get(f));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Although I have one thing I would need to change. I want the filtering to print in the same order as the filter-array, so if I change the place of var1 and var3 in the variables-array, as well as 20 and 30 in the values-array, it should still print out 20, 30. Is it possible? @NinaScholz

Comment: @danielo, it takes always the same order of the filter array. maybe i do not understand the question. please add an example and wanted result.

Comment: @danielo. the last approach uses the `filter` array for the order of the items. when `variables` and `values` changes their order, the `result` order is still given by the `filter` array.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `reduce()` method, and to check if current element exists in other array you can use `indexOf()` which will also give you index of that element.

```js
var arrayOfVariables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'];
var arrayWithValues = [20, 10, 30, 40];
var arrayToFilter = ['var1', 'var3'];

const result = arrayToFilter.reduce(function(r, e) {
  let i = arrayOfVariables.indexOf(e);
  if (i != -1) r.push(arrayWithValues[i])
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.map` and `array.indexOf`

```js
var arrayOfVariables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'];
var arrayWithValues = [20, 10, 30, 40];
var arrayToFilter = ['var1', 'var3'];

// map will return a new array
var m = arrayToFilter.map(function(item) {
  // for every element check if that element is present in arrayOfVariables 
  if (arrayOfVariables.indexOf(item) != -1) {
    // if present get the index and get the value from arrayWithValues
    return arrayWithValues[arrayOfVariables.indexOf(item)]
  }
  return x
})

console.log(m)
```

Comment: It would be preferable to not call `indexOf` twice, since it's a more expensive operation.

Comment: @4castle can i cache in a variable and use it?